# Can I query a collection as part of a Cloud Firestore security rule?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a collection (`DocumentRevisionLog`) made up of documents that include a `lastRevision` field and a `docId` field. I want to reject a create/update if the document's `lastRevision` is less than the total number of documents with the same `docId`.

I'd like to write something like this

```
function lastRevision() {
    return request.resource.data.lastRevision;
}
match /DocumentRevisionLog/{change} {
   allow create, update: if lastRevision() >= 
     // line below is what I'm curious about
     db.collection('DocumentRevisionLog').where('docId', '==', request.resource.data.docId).length;
}
```

Is there a way to query the collection like this in a security rule?

(Here's the Typescript class for the document, if that's helpful)

```
class DocumentManagerChange {
    docId : string;
    actorId : string;
    lastRevision : number;
    op: any;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to run a query in a security rule.  You can only use `get()` to get a single document using its known path.  If you need some sort of count in a rule, you will have to maintain that count in another known document, to be read at the time of the query.